# Executing PHP code using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am currently working on a little project for my PLC.
I use PHP to open a connection to said PLC.

I have created a little website to make interacting easier.

What I want to include on this website is a couple of toggles to send different commands to the device.

I want this done without having to reload the website, so what my researches came up with was to use AJAX.

Now I have tried multiple tutorials on AJAX onclick events using normal buttons and toggles....but none of them gave me the results I wanted.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish what I need?

When the button is pressed I need to execute this php code

```
      $plc->WriteBit("E", 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

When the button is pressed again I need this to execute

```
      $plc->WriteBit("E", 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

All this should work without reloading the site.

Like I said I have really no clue how to parse this php code directly from AJAX. I hope someone can push me in the correct direction!

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to parse anything, you just have to use the PHP file as the URL during the AJAX request. You'll probably want a flag of some sort on the client side to indicate the state of the clicked item. If the state is 'a' call the 'b' PHP file and vice versa.

Comment: Use console on browser to debug your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

**MULTIPLE BUTTONS/ADDRESSES:**

```
<input type='button' name='writeA' value='WRITE BIT A' data-bit='1' data-address='000' class='plc'>
<input type='button' name='writeB' value='WRITE BIT B' data-bit='0' data-address='001' class='plc'>
<div id='output'></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input.plc', function() {
    var bit = parseInt($(this).attr('data-bit'));
    var address = $(this).attr('data-address');
    $('#output').load('plc.php', {'bit':bit, 'address':address});
    $(this).attr('data-bit', bit^1);    // xor bit to toggle value
});
```

PHP script (plc.php):

```
$bit = isset($_POST["bit"]) ? $_POST["bit"] : 0;
$address = isset($_POST["address"]) ? $_POST["address"] : '000';
$lst_address = str_split($address);
$plc->WriteBit("E", $lst_address[0], $lst_address[1], $lst_address[2], $bit);    // or use an 'if' or 'switch' statement    
echo $bit;
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Although it doesn't output the current state of the bit on <div id='output'></div>. It just stays 0.

Comment: The output is currently received from `$plc->WriteBit()`.  If you want the current state of the bit to appear, then just add `$('#output').html(bit);` to the jQuery, or use `echo $bit;` in the PHP.

Comment: Ok that works nicely, any reason why I have to click the button twice for the first time for it to do anything? Also, when creating multiple buttons with unique variables, as soon as I press a button it resets all other buttons.

Comment: The first time you click it it should send `1` to the php script.  Multiple buttons should have unique names but use a generic ajax handler: Give the buttons different names but the same `class='plc'` and use `input.plc` instead of `input:button[name=write_bit]` in the jQuery.

Comment: To explain a bit more. Let's say Button 1 has a status of 0. If I now press Button 2, the first thing that will happen is it will update the status of Button 1 to 1. Another click on Button 2 will set Button 2 to status 1. Why is Button 2 even interfering with Button 1?

Comment: Because it has the same name.  OK I will add code to my post to explain what I mean.

Comment: Ah im sorry I overread when you said to use the same handler. I also forgot to mention that the other Button should change another address. So instead of $plc->WriteBit("E", 0, 0, 0, $bit); it should affect $plc->WriteBit("E", 0, 0, 1, $bit); for example. Which would mean that one generic handler for everything might not be possible like it is right now?  That's why I was confused since Button 2 which affected another Address, changed the Address 1 which was assigned to Button 1.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to send an ajax request on button click. For this you can use jQuery.

```
<button type="button" onclick="callAjax();" value="My Button">My Button</button>
```

Than in callAjax() function you can send an ajax request to a php page.

```
function callAjax(){ //your ajax call will come here }
```

You can check jQuery ajax api here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

In you PHP page print response of your above mentioned fucntion accordingly.

```
echo ($anyFlag == 1)? $plc->WriteBit("E", 0, 0, 0, 1) : $plc->WriteBit("E", 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Than in **success** method of jQuery ajax call you can check response and react accordingly.